# "forward" natural deduction vs "backward" natural deduction

Tags: propositional-calculus, sequent-calculus

#### Updated Question

I'm following [Interactive Tutorial of the Sequent Calculus](http://logitext.mit.edu/tutorial) which states the rules for "backwards" deduction and comparing it to the rules for "forward" natural deduction as stated in the Wikipedia [Sequent Calculus article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus#Natural_deduction_systems).

In general, if the "forward" rule is written as:

$$S_0 \over S_1$$

then the corresponding "backward" rule is written as:

$$S_1 \over S_0$$

For example, the "forward" rule for ${\wedge}R$ is written as (in the Wikipedia article):

$$\Gamma \vdash, \Delta, A \wedge B \over \Gamma \vdash \Delta, A \qquad \Gamma \vdash \Delta, B$$

while the corresponding "backward" rule is written as (in the interactive tutorial, see the summary section at the bottom):

$$\Gamma \vdash \Delta, A \qquad \Gamma \vdash \Delta, B \over \Gamma \vdash, \Delta, A \wedge B$$

Whereas the "forward" deduction system works from top sequents to bottom sequents, the "backward" deduction system works from the bottom sequents to the top sequents -- so isn't it the same? Instead of writing things from top to bottom, we're writing things from bottom to top and applying flipped rules to account for this. Am I correct?

---

The [Interactive Tutorial of the Sequent Calculus](http://logitext.mit.edu/tutorial) also states the rules for using quantification in "backwards" deduction as follows:

|  | L | R |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $$\forall$$ | $$\Gamma, P(z) \vdash \Delta \over \Gamma, \forall xP(x) \vdash \Delta$$ | $$\Gamma \vdash P(x), \Delta \over \Gamma \vdash \forall xP(x), \Delta$$ |
| $$\exists$$ | $$\Gamma, P(x) \vdash \Delta \over \Gamma, \exists xP(x) \vdash \Delta$$ | $$\Gamma \vdash P(z), \Delta \over \Gamma \vdash \exists xP(x), \Delta$$ |

These look like the quantifier rules of LK Calculus. Are they? If not, then these rules are part of the "backward" natural deduction -- are there equivalent "forward" natural deduction rules for quantifiers?

---

#### Original Question

I'm following along to [Interactive Tutorial of the Sequent Calculus](http://logitext.mit.edu/tutorial). It seemingly has the inference rules of "backwards" deduction. E.g. it states ${\wedge}R$ as:

$$\Gamma, A, B \vdash A, \Delta \qquad \Gamma, A, B \vdash B, \Delta \over \Gamma, A , B \vdash A \wedge B, \Delta$$

By contrast, Wikipedia's [Sequent Calculus article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus#Natural_deduction_systems) lists the "forward" natural deduction ${\wedge}R$ as:

$$\Gamma' \vdash, \Delta', A \wedge B \over \Gamma' \vdash \Delta', A \qquad \Gamma' \vdash \Delta', B$$

In the natural deduction version, if you let $\Gamma' = \Gamma, A, B$ and $\Delta' = \Delta$ and flip the sequents (top to bottom, bottom to top), then you get the "backward" deduction rule.

I find the statement of the "backward" deduction rules odd though and harder to apply. They don't seem as general - not because of the flipping, but because of the extra $A, B$ in the hypotheses. Are they equivalent? Is it ok to remove the extra $A, B$?

Another weird statement of a rule is the way the tutorial states the "backwards" ${\neg}L$:

$$\Gamma, A \vdash A, \Delta \over \Gamma, A, \neg A \vdash \Delta$$

What's weird is that under the line is a contradiction ($A \wedge \neg A$). Is it me, or does this make the rules harder to apply?

Why are the rules stated this way?

Comment: Where did you see above "weird" inference rule in your linked ref? I only see similar rules as wikipedea article's in the *Summary* section... Do you mean those in the *Branching rules* section?

Comment: Yes, the ${\wedge}R$ rule I mention in OP I got from **"Branching Rules"**. The site is interactive - click on the $\wedge$ and you'll see $$\Gamma, A, B \vdash A, \Delta \qquad \Gamma, A, B \vdash B, \Delta \over \Gamma, A , B \vdash A \wedge B, \Delta$$

(The first rule in OP.)

I do see at the bottom of the interactive tutorial the summary of the rules and they are indeed the "forward" natural deduction rules from the Wikipedia articles, except they are flipped.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question and hopefully, it's not too noisy.

Re: my original question, I think my confusion was that I was reading

$$\Gamma, A, B \vdash A, \Delta \qquad \Gamma, A, B \vdash B, \Delta \over \Gamma, A , B \vdash A \wedge B, \Delta$$

as the rule itself, but it was actually an application of the rule. As you said further down in the summary of the Interactive Tutorial, the "backward" rules are just flipped versions of the "forward" rules.

Comment: It looks to me like the rules in the Wikipedia table that you call "forwards" are simply written upside-down for no discernible reason.

Comment: If you further read the wiki article to all the rules of LK section, ∧R rule is same as your interactive source.

Comment: Yes. It does look like the interactive source is talking about LK and calling it "backwards" deduction.

Comment: Note in your quoted wikipedea source the rule actually is written as R∧ rule, you inadvertently wrote as ∧R... But in LK section the wikipedea writes the usual ∧R rule. Seems wikipedea authors intentionally flip here.

Comment: As for the "backwards" "forward" rules for quantifiers, these are standard corresponding L/R rules in LK and match wikipedea source. Recall L rules are elim-rules in ND while R rules are intro-rules in ND, you can regard "backwards" here as our main proof search strategy, you don't need to match exactly to L/R rules, it all depends on your goal form based on which you just choose either L or R rules. All rules of LK is listed there already (not that many), no more other "forward/backward" rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing weird here, from your reference it states about backwards deduction feature of sequent calculus:

> In order to show A ∨ B ⊢ A, B is true, you need to show A ⊢ A, B is true and B ⊢ A, B is true." Notice that in both of the subgoals, there no longer is a disjunction; in sequent calculus, we use backwards deduction to get rid of logical operators until we have atomic clauses.

So the author is emphasizing how to use sequent calculus inference rules to get rid of logical connectives in your goal $\Gamma, A , B \vdash A \wedge B, \Delta$ which contains a conjunction. Recall in SC we can have some admissible/derivable rules, but in your above case you can simply view the whole $\Gamma, A , B$ on the left of the turnstile as a multiset $\Gamma'$, then this is just the conventional $\land$ R rule.

As for contradiction on the left of turstile, it's explosion, so any $\Delta$ simply follows...

Comment: thanks! I rewrote the question. Should I post it or edit this one, but keep the current question to give this answer context?

Comment: @joseville If no new question, you can of course edit an existing post. Post a new question if you still have some lingering unanswered question.